# Android TV trick play

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement Trick play Tv app. I have map of timestamp as key and image as a value. At any time there will be only 5 images will be visible.
I am using the `RecyclerView` to implement the auto scrollable list.

I want to store only 5 Visible + 4 = 9 images into the adapter's data source, instead of storing all the images.

Whats the best way to implement this?
Should i use hard coded list of images and replace the images as the seek progress or i should use the RecyclerView with fixed data source size

Thanks in advance.